# using wolfssl mp_init() ,undefined reference to 'sp_init'

Tags: g++, undefined, wolfssl

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wolfssl/options.h>
#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/settings.h>
#include <wolfssl/ssl.h>
#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/sp.h>//cannot to include,why?
#include <wolfssl/wolfcrypt/sp_int.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* arfv[]) {
    mp_int k;
    mp_init(&k);
    return 0;
}
```

I have configured the environment.without `mp_init(&k)`, it can be compiled. I didn't find how to use mp_int in wolfssl document

I didn't find how to use mp_int in wolfssl document.i want to know how to use mp_init and mp_int to calculate in wolfssl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zihao wang

In order to use the MP API directly, you'll need to configure the library to expose them as public using the configuration define `WOLFSSL_PUBLIC_MP`

Here is an example:
https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl-examples/blob/master/ecc/ecc-params.c

Comment: i have configure using './configure --enable-debug --disable-shared CFLAGS="-DWOLFSSL_PUBLIC_MP" && make && sudo make install' according to the example,but it didnot work .could you please go into more detail？thank you very much

Comment: If you build a static lib (`--disable-shared`), then you will need to link the static lib:
`gcc -o ecc-params -I/usr/local/include ecc-params.c /usr/local/lib/libwolfssl.a -lm`